# What does power saving do exactly?

Tags: battery-life

What changes happen in functioning of the phone after you turn it on?

My device: Samsung S3 Mini

Answer (score 1):

I have a Samsung Note and the power saving will lock the max cpu to 1ghz
 (the cpu is meant to run a 1.6) in your phone would be somenthing similar